# How to iterate pandas Dataframe month-wise to satisfy demand over time

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, loops

Suppose I have a dataframe `df`

```
   pd  demand  mon1  mon2  mon3
  abc1     137    46    37    31
  abc2     138    33    37    50
  abc3     120    38    47    46
  abc4     149    39    30    30
  abc5     129    33    42    42
  abc6     112    30    45    43
  abc7     129    43    33    45
```

I want to satisfy the demand of each `pd` month-wise. I am generating some random numbers which indicate satisfied demand. For example, for pd `abc1`, demand is 137, say I have produced 42 units for mon1, but mon1 demand is 46. Hence revised dataframe would be

```
   pd    demand                       mon2                               mon3
  abc1  137 - 42=  95   37 + 4 (Unsatisfied demand for previous month)    31
```

Then it will run for mon2 and so on. In this way, I would like to capture, how much demand would be satisfied for each `pd` (excess or unsatisfied).

My try:

```
import pandas as pd
import random
mon = ['mon1', 'mon2', 'mon3']

for i in df['pd'].values.tolist():
    t = df.loc[df['pd'] == i, :]
    for m in t.columns[2:]:
        y = t[m].iloc[0]
        n = random.randint(20, 70)
        t['demand'] = t['demand'].iloc[0] - n
```

Not finding the logic exactly.

Comment: Is 42 expected to be subtracted from the demands of every pd?

Comment: Also, what happened to your mon1 column in your sample output?

Comment: where is 42 coming from?

Comment: @aaossa Yes, 42 expected to be subtracted from the demands for ```pd = abc1```. This value might be different for ```pd=abc2```. Not 42, but the produced demand. I do not want to consider mon1 column while doing jobs for mon2. That is not a sample output, sample output will be how much demand would be satisfied for each pd after 3 months.

Comment: @enke 42 is coming through random number generation. This value might be different. Value is not important, you can take any value instead of 42. This thing is, you have adjust total demand as well monthly demand based on this value.

Comment: If you'll always consider only 3 months, isn't this the same as adding the initial demand plus all of the other columns and then substracting your production? Something like `demand + mon1 + mon2 + mont3 - 42`?

Comment: @aaossa Yes! That is okay! But the thing is, I need to do it monthly basis. 42 is not fixed. Say for abc1, in mon1, produced qty is 42, but in next month, it might be 55 or some thing else. Again, sample output will be **how much demand would be satisfied for each pd after 3 months** if you generate some random numbers 20 & 70 in each month.